# How to get the count of selected values in a dropdown using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a HTML like this. I need to get the selected value's count using the  tag. How to do that using jQuery.

```
<select id="availability1">
  <option value="Available">Available</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>
</select>

<select id="availability2">
  <option value="Available">Available</option>
  <option value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>
</select>

<select id="availability3">
  <option value="Available">Available</option>
  <option value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>
</select>

<select id="availability4">
  <option value="Available">Available</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Scheduled">Scheduled</option>
  <option value="Unavailable">Unavailable</option>
</select>
```

How to get the selected values which are Scheduled. The ids have a pattern availability(X). How to write this using jQuery. The output I expect is 2 since there are two selected tags which are Scheduled.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this using [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
var scheduled = ​$("select").filter(function() {
                  return $(this).val() == "Scheduled";
                })​​​​​​;
alert(scheduled.length);​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/hP5nW/), this takes all the `<select>` elements, then does a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the ones with a selected value of "Scheduled", then we're just alerting the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) to see how many of those there were.